# turn off all service playing music in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I use Alarm manager for stop all music are playing in android. But I don't know how do this. 
In main activity source code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, OneShotAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this,
                0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

        // Schedule the alarm!
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

and Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
```

{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{  
// What can I do for stop music of device is running
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.one_shot_received, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can look into: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29)

Something like this should work:

```
AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

EDIT:
There is a function to take "Audio Focus": [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus%28android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public int requestAudioFocus (AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener l, int streamType, int durationHint)
```

[Sample](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html)

```
AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...

// Request audio focus for playback
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                                 // Use the music stream.
                                 AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                 // Request permanent focus.
                                 AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
    // Start playback.
}
```

Comment: I can do it with AudioManager, but volumn is turn off and music still running( haven't sound ). How can I stop service is playing music?

Comment: I can set volumn mute by audioManager. But I want turn off media player is running music in android. :(